# Updating array item property in loop, updated property value is not maintained after loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, for-loop

In the below loop I update `ref.shader.edgeColor` and `ref.shader.faceColor` with a calculated alpha.

```
    for (let i = 0; i < this._polyRenderRefs.length; i++) {
        let ref = this._polyRenderRefs[i];
        let poly = this._polygons[ref.polygonIndex];

        let alpha = 1.0 - (poly.position.z - this._zDepthMin) / (this._zDepthMax - this._zDepthMin);
        ref.shader.edgeColor.setAlpha(alpha);
        ref.shader.faceColor.setAlpha(alpha);

        this._polyRender.drawSingle(context, poly, ref);
    }
```

In `_polyRender.drawSingle()` I use that alpha when drawing the polygon. This produces the following output.

[image: alpha is correct]

If I move the `_polyRender.drawSingle()` into a loop immediately following where I set the new alpha, the property is no longer modified.

```
    for (let i = 0; i < this._polyRenderRefs.length; i++) {
        let ref = this._polyRenderRefs[i];
        let poly = this._polygons[ref.polygonIndex];

        let alpha = 1.0 - (poly.position.z - this._zDepthMin) / (this._zDepthMax - this._zDepthMin);
        ref.shader.edgeColor.setAlpha(alpha);
        ref.shader.faceColor.setAlpha(alpha);

        // this._polyRender.drawSingle(context, poly, ref);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < this._polyRenderRefs.length; i++) {
        let ref = this._polyRenderRefs[i];
        let poly = this._polygons[ref.polygonIndex];

        this._polyRender.drawSingle(context, poly, ref);
    }
```

Using the same `_polyRender.drawSingle()` method. Using the same index of the same array.  It produces the following output.
[image: alpha is incorrect]

This shows that `_polyRenderRefs[i]` was updated.
[image: array item updated]

Then in the next loop it has no longer been updated
[image: array item no longer updated]

I have also tried without using variables to reference the array items. I get the same results.

```
    for (let i = 0; i < this._polyRenderRefs.length; i++) {            
        let alpha = 1.0 - (this._polygons[this._polyRenderRefs[i].polygonIndex].position.z - this._zDepthMin) / (this._zDepthMax - this._zDepthMin);
        this._polyRenderRefs[i].shader.edgeColor.setAlpha(alpha);
        this._polyRenderRefs[i].shader.faceColor.setAlpha(alpha);

        // this._polyRender.drawSingle(context, poly, ref);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < this._polyRenderRefs.length; i++) {
        this._polyRender.drawSingle(context, this._polygons[this._polyRenderRefs[i].polygonIndex], this._polyRenderRefs[i]);
    }
```

What is going on here? Am I accessing the array incorrectly?

### Update 1

The problem seems to be with the alpha calculation. If I calculate using the `poly.position.z`, the alpha does not remain updated outside of the loop. If I put a number, like 10, in the place of `poly.position.z` the alpha is updated outside the loop and everything works as expected.

```
for (let i = 0; i < this._polyRenderRefs.length; i++) {
    let ref = this._polyRenderRefs[i];
    let poly = this._polygons[ref.polygonIndex];

    let zPosition = poly.position.z; // does not update alpha outside of this loop
    //let zPosition = 10; // correctly updates alpha outside of this loop

    let alpha = 1 - (zPosition - this._zDepthMin) / (this._zDepthMax - this._zDepthMin);

    ref.shader.edgeColor.setAlpha(alpha);
    ref.shader.faceColor.setAlpha(alpha);
}
```

`position` is a vec3 from `gl-matrix`. I access the values from the float32 array like so...

```
import { vec3 } from 'gl-matrix';

export class Vertex {
    private _vertex: vec3;

    public get x() { return this._vertex[0]; }
    public get y() { return this._vertex[1]; }
    public get z() { return this._vertex[2]; }
    public get value(): vec3 { return this._vertex; }

    constructor(x: number, y: number, z: number = 0) {
        this._vertex = vec3.fromValues(x, y, z);
    }
}
```

### Update 2

I assumed the alpha was default after leaving the loop, but I was incorrect. The issue appears to be that `ref.shader.edgeColor.alpha` and `ref.shader.faceColor.alpha` on every item in the loop is referencing the `alpha` variable in the for loop. So once the last item calculates alpha, all items are updated to the latest calculated value.

How do I break that relationship?

`polyRenderRef`

```
export class PolygonRenderReference {
    public get polygonId(): string { return this._polygonId; }
    private _index: number = -1;
    private _polygonId: string = '';

    public get polygonIndex(): number { return this._index; }

    public shader: CanvasShader;

    constructor(polygonIndex: number, polygonId: string, shader: CanvasShader) {
        this._index = polygonIndex;
        this._polygonId = polygonId;
        this.shader = shader;
    }
}
```

`shader`

```
export class CanvasShader{
    public drawEdge: boolean = true;
    public edgeWidth: number = 1;
    public edgeColor: Color = new Color();

    public drawFace: boolean = true;
    public faceColor: Color = new Color();
}
```

`Color`

```
export class Color {
    private _shade: string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern;
    public get shade(): string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern {
        return this._shade;
    }

    public _alpha: number = 1;
    public get alpha(): number { return this._alpha; }

    constructor(shade: string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern = '#888') {
        this._shade = shade;
    }

    setShade(shade: string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern) {
        this._shade = shade;
    }

    setAlpha(alpha: number): void {
        this._alpha = Math.fround(alpha);
    }
}
```

### Update 3

I added a test variable in `PolygonRenderReference` and updated it in the loop. Each item updated independently like expected.

I added a test variable in `CanvasShader` and updated it in the loop. Each loop updated all test variables in the array to be the same value.

So Something is going on with how the `CanvasShader` is referenced on the `PolygonRenderReference` item in the loop.

### Solution

At an earlier point in my app, I built up the array of `PolyRenderRefs`. I had overlooked that I was not creating a new shader for each item, but I was referencing the same shader object for each item. So when I updated the alpha, it updated that reference for all array items.

Comment: It might be valuable to include what any of these things are (e.g., what actually **is** `_polygons`), what's being used for this (e.g., is it WebGL or a library or...?), and so on. Clearly the value is being set, but w/o context it'd be difficult to understand why it isn't set later.

Comment: @DaveNewton I updated with more information.

Comment: `alpha` is local to that loop, and (AFAICT) is an immediate value--it can't be "held on to" or anything. The shader, on the other hand, could be--are you certain you're dealing with different instances of shaders (or edge/face colors, or the `poly` ref)? In other words: if there's a single shader (or the others) updating it w/ the new alpha would mean every ref would see that updated value.

Comment: The nutshell is that it's a bit difficult to diagnose w/o just running the debugger. `alpha` in the loop, if its a number, can't really change itself on its own outside of the loop, meaning there's probably something more fundamentally wrong.

Comment: @DaveNewton you nailed it. When I was creating the poly's I was using one shader to set them all. So when I updated the value it updated the reference for all. I now create a new shader for each reference. I should have been looking one level higher instead of digging deeper.

Comment: Niiiice, glad you worked it out 